# Critical Point for Nonlinear System of Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I'm asked to find the critical points of the following nonlinear system and identify their nature

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-(2+y)(x+y)\;\;\;\frac{dy}{dt}=-y(1-x)$$

Clearly my points are

$$p_1=(0,0),\;\;p_2=(1,-1),\;\;p_3=(1,-2)$$

My problem is with finding the local nature of the origin. I consider the following Jacobian matrix

$$J=\begin{bmatrix}-2-y&-2-x-2y\\y&x-1\end{bmatrix}$$

Evaluated at the origin this clearly gives me

$$J|_{(0,0)}=\begin{bmatrix}-2&-2\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$$

This has a characteristic polynomial of

$$\lambda^2+3\lambda+2=0$$

However, this system should locally behave like $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: I should have clarified that I was given a phase portrait of the system and its local portrait is that of a system with redundant eigenvalue

Comment: Okay thank you, my book is probably misprinted then